# Python code to scan network to obtain the computer name

Tags: python, networking, programming-languages

I need to run a network scan to obtain the computer name of the PCs connected to the network.
This is to run a software compliance scan on these systems.

We require the name of the system in  order to connect to their registry to obtain information.

How do we obtain computer name or is their any other way to connect to the computers inthe network ?

Comment: "computer name" is a very general term. Specify what excactly you need. (like DNS-Name, NetBIOS, WINS, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably just use an IP address rather than a name. System calls in Windows that requires a machine name will generally also accept a numeric address just the same.

e.g. these both work:

```
>>> import _winreg
>>> c = _winreg.ConnectRegistry("SOMEMACHINE", _winreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT)
>>> c = _winreg.ConnectRegistry("10.10.40.9", _winreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Very windows specific hack that works okay.

```
import subprocess

def get_host(target):
    pro = subprocess.Popen(['ping','-a', '-n', '1', target], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
    return pro.communicate()[0]

def parse_hostname(result):
    return result.split()[1]

def get_range(network, start, finish):
    while start != finish:
        target = network + start
        yield parse_hostname(get_host(target))
        start += 1
```